# react-native-maps does not work after build the app using expo?

Tags: react-native

**Problem:**
I have created a react native application with expo clii. In there I am using react-native-maps.With expo app It was very worked. But after building the standalone app  and when I try to open it it did not navigate to that component.It mean when I click on the location tab it restart the app.This is my that component code.

```
import React, { Component } from "react";

import {
  StyleSheet,
  KeyboardAvoidingView,
  View,
  ActivityIndicator,
  TouchableOpacity,
  TextInput,
  Text,
  Image,
  ScrollView,
  Dimensions
} from "react-native";

import MapView from "react-native-maps";

import PageHeader from "../Shared/pageHeader/PageHeader";

const windowheight = (Dimensions.get("window").height * 75) / 100;
const windowwidth = (Dimensions.get("window").width * 80) / 100;

class Location extends Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);

    this.state = {
      focusedLocation: {
        latitude: 6.9336686,
        longitude: 79.8489527,
        latitudeDelta: 0.0322,
        longitudeDelta:
          (Dimensions.get("window").width / Dimensions.get("window").height) *
          0.0322
      },
      locationChosen: false,
      placesList: [],
      isFocused: false
    };
  }

  static navigationOptions = {
    header: null
  };

  componentDidMount() {
    navigator.geolocation.getCurrentPosition(
      pos => {
        const coordsEvent = {
          nativeEvent: {
            coordinate: {
              latitude: pos.coords.latitude,
              longitude: pos.coords.longitude
            }
          }
        };

        this.pickLocationHandler(coordsEvent);
      },
      err => {
        console.log(err);
        alert("Fetching the Position failed");
      }
    );
  }

  reloadLocation = () => {
    navigator.geolocation.getCurrentPosition(
      pos => {
        const coordsEvent = {
          nativeEvent: {
            coordinate: {
              latitude: pos.coords.latitude,
              longitude: pos.coords.longitude
            }
          }
        };

        this.pickLocationHandler(coordsEvent);
      },
      err => {
        console.log(err);
        alert("Fetching the Position failed");
      }
    );
  };

  pickLocationHandler = event => {
    this.setState({ locationChosen: true });
    const coords = event.nativeEvent.coordinate;
    let placesList = [];
    let places = [];
    this.map.animateToRegion({
      ...this.state.focusedLocation,
      latitude: coords.latitude,
      longitude: coords.longitude
    });
    const apikey = "AIzaSyDsA9zWFxw__OiApEKhbUEqVL4VQ_uN0hc";
    fetch(
      "https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/place/nearbysearch/json?location=" +
        coords.latitude +
        "," +
        coords.longitude +
        "&radius=800" +
        "&type=parking" +
        "&key=" +
        apikey
    )
      .then(response => response.json())
      .then(responseJson => {
        if (responseJson) {
          placesList = responseJson.results;
          placesList.map((el, index) => {
            var place = {
              title: el.name,
              coordinates: {
                latitude: el.geometry.location.lat,
                longitude: el.geometry.location.lng
              }
            };
            places.push(place);
          });
          this.setState({ placesList: places });
        }
      });
  };

  componentWillUnmount = () => {
    this.setState(prevState => {
      return {
        focusedLocation: {
          ...prevState.focusedLocation,
          latitude: 6.9336686,
          longitude: 79.8489527
        },
        locationChosen: false,
        placesList: []
      };
    });
  };

  render() {
    let marker = null;
    if (this.state.locationChosen) {
      marker = <MapView.Marker coordinate={this.state.focusedLocation} />;
    }

    const places = this.state.placesList;

    return (
      <View>
        <PageHeader
          title="Nearby Parking"
          image={require("../../../assets/shape.png")}
          width="4%"
          marginTop="1.5%"
          marginLeft="40%"
        ></PageHeader>
        <View
          style={{
            marginTop: "2%",
            marginBottom: "2%",
            marginLeft: "2%",
            marginRight: "2%"
          }}
        >
          <MapView
            style={styles.map}
            provider="google"
            initialRegion={this.state.focusedLocation}
            showsUserLocation={true}
            zoomControlEnabled={true}
            style={styles.map}
            onPress={this.pickLocationHandler}
            onUserLocationChange={this.reloadLocation}
            ref={ref => (this.map = ref)}
          >
            {places.map((place, index) => {
              return (
                <MapView.Marker
                  key={index}
                  coordinate={place.coordinates}
                  title={place.title}
                  pinColor="red"
                  tooltip={true}
                />
              );
            })}
            {marker}
          </MapView>
        </View>
      </View>
    );
  }
}

const styles = StyleSheet.create({
  map: {
    height: "100%",
    width: "100%"
  },
  button: {
    margin: 8,
    backgroundColor: "#fff",
    borderWidth: 1,
    borderColor: "#fff",
    alignItems: "center",
    justifyContent: "center",
    width: 50,
    height: 50,
    borderRadius: 100,
    marginTop: windowheight,
    marginLeft: windowwidth
  },
  callout: {},
  calloutButton: {
    marginTop: windowheight,
    marginLeft: windowwidth,
    borderWidth: 1,
    borderColor: "rgba(0,0,0,0.2)",
    alignItems: "center",
    justifyContent: "center",
    width: 50,
    height: 50,
    backgroundColor: "#2b78fe",
    borderRadius: 100,
    shadowColor: "#e9ebee"
  }
});

export default Location;
```

Can someone tell me what kind of reason would cause this issue.Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

### Modify the following

1. Add `flex: 1` to your parent view:

```
// ... other code

      <View style={{ flex: 1 }}>                         <=== add flex here
        <PageHeader
          title="Nearby Parking"
          image={require("../../../assets/shape.png")}

// ... other code
```

2. Change your map styling to the following:

```
map: {
    flex: 1
}
```

3. Remove the duplicate declaration of style on the

```
// ... other code

<MapView
            style={styles.map}
            provider="google"
            initialRegion={this.state.focusedLocation}
            showsUserLocation={true}
            zoomControlEnabled={true}
            style={styles.map}                          <=== remove this
            onPress={this.pickLocationHandler}
            onUserLocationChange={this.reloadLocation}
            ref={ref => (this.map = ref)}>

// ... other code
```

4. The correct way to use the GOOGLE provider

```
import MapView, { PROVIDER_GOOGLE, Marker } from 'react-native-maps'

// ... other code

<MapView
            style={styles.map}
            provider={PROVIDER_GOOGLE}                  <=== make this chage
            initialRegion={this.state.focusedLocation}
            showsUserLocation={true}
            zoomControlEnabled={true}
            style={styles.map}
            onPress={this.pickLocationHandler}
            onUserLocationChange={this.reloadLocation}
            ref={ref => (this.map = ref)}>

// ... other code
```

Hope this Helps!